# Regex check if number excludes specific digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number with a length of 10 digits, and I want to check if my number contains 0 or 2 at any position.
How can I achieve this with regex?

Comment: why no use some function like includes or indexOf

Comment: `[13-9]+` might be what you are looking for

Comment: I would prefer indexOf over regex, as it can be overhead for this particular purpose.

Comment: Do you actually have a length requirement on your number, or could there be a length requirement in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^\d*[02]\d*$` to check 0 or 2

`^\d*[02]\d*$` : `^` starts with

- `\d*`  : zero or more digits
- `[02]` : match `0` or `2`
- `\d*`  : match zero or more digits then `$` mean end of match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAXlws/2)

```js
 
console.log(/^\d*[02]\d*$/.test('1111011111')); 
console.log(/^\d*[02]\d*$/.test('1111211111')); 
console.log(/^\d*[02]\d*$/.test('1111111111'));
```

Although the easy and neat option would be using `indexOf` as suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483421/regex-check-if-number-excludes-specific-digits/44483493#comment75960950_44483421)

```js
var num = "1111110111";
var num_invalid = "1111111111";
if(num.indexOf("0") >=0 || num.indexOf("2")>=0) 
{
    console.log("0 or 2");       
}else{console.log("Invalid number");}

if(num_invalid.indexOf("0") >=0 || num_invalid.indexOf("2")>=0) 
{
    console.log("0 or 2");       
}else{console.log("Invalid number");}
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict to 10 numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP never said the regex has to enforce a length of 10 characters. Quite the opposite, really. They say they _have_ a number with 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Use regEx as `/[02]/g` which search for atleast one occorance of 0 or 2 in every digit

```js
function test(elmt){
var reg=/[02]/g;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=!reg.test(elmt.value);
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="test(this)"/>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that your number has 10 digits *and* that 0 or 2 appear at least once somewhere, then a lookahead might be the simplest way to do this.

```
^(?=.*[02])\d{10}$
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
var isContain = false;
var no = 1234567890;
if(no.toString().split("").indexOf("2")>=0 || 
no.toString().split("").indexOf("0")>=0){
isContain = true;
}
```